# Swift buttons array fatal error: Array index out of range

Tags: arrays, swift, button, fatal-error

Please help. I have fatal error: Array index out of range.
When i have 2 or 1 coins and aiTurn takes 3, i have fatal error.
Where i do wrong?
Thanks...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {    
    @IBOutlet var coins: [UIButton]!
    @IBOutlet weak var endTurn: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

@IBAction func endTurn(sender: UIButton) {       
     aiTurn(sender)
    }

    func aiTurn(sender: UIButton!) {
        var i = Int(arc4random_uniform(3))
            var btnsendtag:UIButton = sender
            if btnsendtag.tag == 22 {
                   var usignedRandomNumber : Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(coins!.count)))
                    var randomNumber = Int(usignedRandomNumber)
                    for i; i >= 0; --i {
                    self.coins?[i].hidden = true
                        self.coins?.removeAtIndex(i)
                        var dol = coins.count - i
                        println(dol)
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Your code seems incomplete (missing braces) and it's badly formatted. Also you are not giving enough information: where does the error happen? How many `coins` do you have?

Comment: 21 coins. This line is fatal error:  self.coins?[i].hidden = true

Answer (score 0):

This line makes no sense:

```
for i; i >= 0; --i {
```

If you're going to use that form of for loop you need to initialize the value to something:

```
for i = Int(arc4random_uniform(3)); i >= 0; --i
```

Comment: self.coins?[i].hidden = true